# I create my LSTM Keras2 model , use AveragePooling2D, but NameError: name 'AveragePooling2D' is not defined

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I want to make a model for training in time series Use Keras 2 and analysis dataset 20x6 size. What do I additionally need to import or what version of Keras is needed for this?

```
##enter code here
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.add(AveragePooling2D())

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=RMSprop(lr=.01))
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=6000, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

Comment: may be you didn't imported it? try from keras.layers import AveragePooling2D

Answer (score 0):

Greeting

Did you import AveragePooling2D?

I don't think you did.

Add this on you code:
**import tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D**